# How to set a predefined object selected in Related To field of Task Object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tasks, taskrelation

I need to have the pre selected object to be Account. It is alphabetically ordered at the moment. This might be a salesforce limitation, so if you may have encountered the same, please let me know your work around. Thanks!

[image]